# R Group Data, determine duplicates, update column on the earliest instance

Tags: r, select

I'm needing some help to determine if a 'title' has ever been 'registered' and if so, update a separate column with the earliest date in for that title with text - "InsinuatedRegistered".

I've tried a bunch of things but don't know how to select only the earliest item to add the text to.

try:

```
listin %>% group_by(title, Action_updated=="Registration") %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(Action_updated = "InsinuatedRegistered")
```

[listin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgL35.png)

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data instead of image.  Also, not clear what you expct

Comment: If not opposed to base R, consider `ave` + `ifelse`: `within(listin, { Action_updated <- ifelse(ave(Effective, title, FUN=min) == Effective, "Insinuated Registered", Action) })`.

Comment: OMG that's it! A huge thanks - I've spent hours trying to figure that out.